# Binomial Coefficients: Summation and Floor Function Identities

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

An exercise for my stochastic processes class is asking me to prove that

\begin{equation} \sum_{k=0}^{\left \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \right \rfloor } \begin{pmatrix} n \\ 2k+1  \end{pmatrix} 5^k \end{equation}

is always an integer multiple of $(2^{n-1})$, that is

\begin{equation} \sum_{k=0}^{\left \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \right \rfloor } \begin{pmatrix} n \\ 2k+1  \end{pmatrix} 5^k = p(2^{n-1}), \quad p \in \mathbb{N}\end{equation}

Some identities which seem helpful for this situation but which I have not quite figured out how to apply are the following:

\begin{equation}\begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \lfloor n/2 \rfloor \\ \lfloor k/2 \rfloor \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} n \mod 2 \\ k \mod 2 \end{pmatrix} \mod 2 \end{equation}

and

\begin{equation} \sum_{k=0}^n k\begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix} = n2^{n-1}\end{equation}

Could someone please suggest some identities that may be helpful or point me to a resource where I might find some useful identities?

Comment: Um, the identity $\binom nk \equiv \binom{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{\lfloor k/2\rfloor} \pmod 2$ is just wrong: e.g., $\binom63 = 20$ is even but $\binom31 = 3$ is odd. The correct identity is $\binom nk \equiv \binom{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{\lfloor k/2\rfloor} \binom{n \bmod 2}{k \bmod 2} \pmod 2$, a variant of [Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem).

Comment: @MishaLavrov I was using the theorems proved in these notes http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cs4205/files/CM4.pdf . I will edit my post to reflect the correction.

Comment: The theorem you probably got this from, Theorem 4.1.10, says that this holds unless $n$ is even and $k$ is odd, in which case we always get $\binom nk \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$. That's equivalent to the above, since $\binom{n \bmod 2}{k \bmod 2}$ is either $0$ (when it is $\binom 01$) or $1$ (in the three other cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only identity you really need here is the binomial theorem:
$$
   \binom n0 + \binom n1 x + \binom n2 x^2 + \dots + \binom{n}{n-1}x^{n-1} + \binom nn x^n = (1 + x)^n.
$$
By replacing $x$ with $-x$, we get:
$$
   \binom n0 + \binom n1 (-x) + \binom n2 (-x)^2 + \dots + \binom{n}{n-1}(-x)^{n-1} + \binom nn (-x)^n = (1 - x)^n.
$$
You should ponder the relationship between these two sums and how you may use them to obtain the sum in your question, which only includes the odd terms.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see now what I must do.